# Can I config CMake not to clean some files once generated?

Tags: makefile, cmake

Very often we use some third-party open source libraries in our project. For example, Google test framework or Intel PCM. To make our project code portable I usually include their sources as part of my project's source tree and add them as CMake's sub-directories. However, the compiled objects of these third-party libraries need not be re-built every time `make clean` is called. Is there a way I can configure in CMake such that once these libraries are built on a machine, it is not cleaned by the clean target?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such features, but you could use cunning and the `CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM` directory property combined with a custom command to build the considered side libraries:

```
add_subdirectory(source_dir [binary_dir] CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM)
```

This property tells that *"the outputs of custom commands for this directory will not be removed during the* `make clean` *stage"* (see the lightweight related [cmake doc](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_dir/CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM.html)).